# How to create bibliography for german thesis, preferably according to the german standard DIN~1505 with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

For my Ph. D. thesis I want to create a bibliography according to the suggestions given in the german standard **DIN 1505**.

There exists a quite old style dinat.bst (see [TeXFAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/dinat/dinat-index.html)) which I had used in a slightly modified version for my diploma thesis many years ago.

I read a lot of positive things about `biblatex` and I'm currently planning to switch from my old `bibtex` to `biblatex` to hopefully better configure the bibliography.

However it would be very helpful (and I'm quite sure somebody must have done this before me) to have a readily configured citation style which corresponds (or comes close to) to the DIN 1505 and which works with `biblatex` (even if it is not perfect). 
I did not find anything about that in the `biblatex` manual, but maybe I've overlooked it...

---

I found 2 documents defining the requirements:
*(I'm sorry: they're both in German which makes sense, as it is a german standard.)*

- [Das Literaturverzeichnis in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten : Erstellung bibliographischer Belege nach DIN 1505 Teil 2 von Klaus F. Lorenzen (2nd ed, Jan 1997)](http://www.bui.haw-hamburg.de/fileadmin/redaktion/diplom/Lorenzen__litverz.pdf)
- [Kurzreferenz Zitieren (v 1.0, 1999)](http://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/fachbereich_physik/didaktik_physik/materialien/materialschlichting/zitierregeln.pdf) *this is a short and simplified description*

Comment: I remember seeing a similar question somewhere before. At the time, it did not seem entirely clear that there was a definite style required. Could you either post or link to a detailed list of requirements?

Comment: @Joseph: good question - I edited my question. Unfortunately, the materials I've found are in german language only.

Comment: @Joseph: Maybe it was [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14814/online-discussion-about-general-questions-for-scientific-writing/14815#14815).

Comment: I don’t think that there exists a ready-to-use solution, but you could take biblatex’s authoryear style as a starting point, if you really have to use the DIN 1505 style. [This discussion on mrunix.de](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=71474) might help you with the label.

Comment: @domwass: I'd definitely not use the author-year-citations, as they consume too much space (>4 pages more in about 200 of the main body, when using author-year style instead of numeric). So I'll have to find a solution of my own, it seems. (which could be adapting an existing style to match the DIN OR deciding not to care about the DIN and use another style..).

Comment: @Martin, as you referred to dinat (which should not be used any more, since natdin is more up to date), I thought you wanted to have Author-Year citations. You can of course build a DIN style based upon biblatex’s numeric style. Which of biblatex‘s features do you need to use? If none, I would stick with natdin.

Comment: I'd also appreciate a ready-made `biblatex` style compatible with DIN 1505 - unfortunately, I couldn't find one one the Internet, so you'll have to create your own. [Dominik Waßenhoven's articles (in German)](http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de/dtk.shtml), especially part 2, explain how to do this.

Comment: @domwass: I thought that `biblatex` is "the future" - I admit that I have not in detail compared the features, but I read that it assembles the functionality of a large number of separate packages and that is highly configurable to do what it is supposed to do. I had hoped that there would already be a biblatex style for DIN.

Comment: @Martin, true, biblatex is “the future”, but if you have to invest a lot of time to get a DIN 1505 style and if you don’t need any of the other functionalities offered by biblatex (and biber) – like true utf8 support, for instance –, then it might be worth to stick with a functioning bst and traditional BibTeX for the moment. If you do need (one of) the functionalities, you have to build your own style, as @diabonas said.

Comment: @domwass: Please convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think that there is a ready-to-use solution, but you could take biblatex’s authoryear style as a starting point, if you really have to use the DIN 1505 style. [This discussion on mrunix.de](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=71474) might help you with the label. Be aware, though, that you have to invest a lot of time to get a DIN 1505 style and if you don’t need any of the other functionalities offered by biblatex (and biber) – like true utf8 support, for instance – then it might be worth to stick with a functioning `bst` and traditional BibTeX for the moment. If you do need (one of) the functionalities, you have to build your own style, as @diabonas said.

Comment: Hi Dominik, are you aware that anyone in the last three or four years has invested in creating a conforming biblatex style? The question comes up every once in a while and nobody seems to have done it. As you said, quite a lot of work. We could start a github rep and invite people to contribute. Maybe Frank (http://texwelt.de/blog/modifizieren-eines-biblatex-stils/), Ulrike, Clemens, and other guys from the german community. i think all of us are somehow floating around TeXwelt or here.

Comment: Looking at 1505 and the successor ISO 690 leads to a new google search and to https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690