# Custom authoryear bibstyle to match German dinat

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use `biblatex` in my document like this:

```
  \usepackage[backend=biber,
            hyperref=true,
            sorting=none,
            url=true,
            isbn=false,
            citestyle=authoryear-comp,
            bibstyle=authoryear,
            mergedate=true,
            dashed=false,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none,
            eprint=false,
            urldate=comp,
            dateabbrev=false,
            natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

Which generates a bibliography that looks like this:

[image: no description]

I wish to follow the German `dinat` style bibliography as closely as I can without getting too overwhelmingly complex if possible and without using `natbib`. An example of that would look like this:

[image]

How could I go about accomplishing that? The `citestyle` is already ideal and I do not want to change that. [Here](http://pastebin.com/JKCkXwcV) is the bibliography file:

```
@inproceedings{crabb2008real,
 title={Real-time foreground segmentation via range and color imaging},
 author={Crabb, Ryan and Tracey, Colin and Puranik, Akshaya and Davis, James},
 booktitle={IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition Workshops, 2008. CVPRW'08.},
 pages={1--5},
 year={2008},
 organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{cui20103d,
 title={3D shape scanning with a time-of-flight camera},
 author={Cui, Yan and Schuon, Sebastian and Chan, Derek and Thrun, Sebastian and Theobalt, Christian},
 booktitle={IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR), 2010 },
 pages={1173--1180},
 year={2010},
 organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{biswas2011gesture,
 title={Gesture Recognition using Microsoft Kinect{\textregistered}},
 author={Biswas, KK and Basu, Saurav Kumar},
 booktitle={5th International Conference on Automation, Robotics and Applications (ICARA), 2011},
 pages={100--103},
 year={2011},
 organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{wang20123d,
 title={3D scene reconstruction by multiple structured-light based commodity depth cameras},
 author={Wang, Jianfeng and Zhang, Cha and Zhu, Wenwu and Zhang, Zhengyou and Xiong, Zixiang and Chou, Philip A},
 booktitle={IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP), 2012},
 pages={5429--5432},
 year={2012},
 organization={IEEE}
}

@incollection{herbrechtsmeier2009bebot,
 title={Bebot: A modular mobile miniature robot platform supporting hardware reconfiguration and multi-standard communication},
 author={Herbrechtsmeier, Stefan and Witkowski, Ulf and R{\"u}ckert, Ulrich},
 booktitle={Progress in Robotics},
 pages={346--356},
 year={2009},
 publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Sadly there doesn't seem to be a package for biblatex. Can you provide the bib file?

Comment: I seem to remember there was a `biblatex` package lurking around somewhere (it didn't make it to CTAN though). There are some questions surrounding DIN style here [Is there a BibLaTeX equivalent for the BibTeX style “alphadin” for the DIN 1505 Standard](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124473/35864), [How to create bibliography for german thesis, preferably according to the german standard DIN~1505 with biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23321/35864), [Suppress \unspace command to force biblatex to add spaces (DIN 1505)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130448/35864).

Comment: Is it just [`dinat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dinat) you want to copy, or is there any other style guide you want to follow?

Comment: I have added the bib file. I only want to copy `dinat`.